# Adding parameters to a user created via the sync gateway REST API

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

The couchbase sync gateway REST API allows for the inclusion of an email address in the JSON that is `PUT` at the registration URI `_user/<foo>`. In my use case I'd like to implement phone number registration via SMS and to include the phone number in the sync gateway user record created in the bucket. This will avoid my having to create a separate document to store a phone number in. Is there any way to specify custom fields that can be included in the JSON sent via the `PUT` method?

Comment: I don't think it's currently supported. But you should open a feature request on the sync_gateway repo on GitHub. Seems like a useful functionality to have.